# Having trouble with user defined assignment operator for class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization, assignment-operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Register.h"

int main() {
    // Basic constructors
    Reg8  r8{ 0xC4 };
    Reg16 r16{ 0x1234 };
    Reg32 r32{ 0x89ABCDEF };
    Reg64 r64{ 0xABBA04200240ABBA };

    // I can do this with similar types:
    Reg8  r8b  = r8;  // okay
    Reg16 r16b = r16; // okay
    Reg32 r32b = r32; // okay
    Reg64 r64b = r64; // okay

    Reg8  r8c;
    r8c  = r8;  // okay
    Reg16 r16c;
    r16c = r16; // okay
    Reg32 r32c;
    r32c = r32; // okay
    Reg64 r64c;
    r64c = r64; // okay

    // Attempting with different Register Types.
    // Now Fixed by doing the following:
    // Reg16 r16d = r8; // Not okay - need to static_cast it.
    Reg16 r16d = static_cast<Reg16>(r8); // okay

    // What I would like to do:
    Reg16 r16e;
    r16e = r32; // not okay:

    // NOTE: You can see some of my attempts of overloading
    // specializing the operator=() below the class section.

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Register.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace vpc {
    using u8  = std::uint8_t;
    using u16 = std::uint16_t;
    using u32 = std::uint32_t;
    using u64 = std::uint64_t;

    template<typename T>
    struct Register;

    using Reg8  = Register<u8>;
    using Reg16 = Register<u16>;
    using Reg32 = Register<u32>;
    using Reg64 = Register<u64>;

    template<typename T>
    struct Register {
        T value;
        T previous_value;
        std::bitset<sizeof(T)* CHAR_BIT> bits;

        Register() : value{ 0 }, previous_value{ 0 }, bits{ 0 } {}

        template<typename V, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(V) > sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
        explicit Register(const V val, const u8 idx = 0) :
            value{ static_cast<T>((val >> std::size(bits) * idx) &
                  std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max()) },
            previous_value{ 0 },
            bits{ value }
        {
            constexpr u16 sizeT = sizeof(T);
            constexpr u16 sizeP = sizeof(V);
            assert((idx >= 0) && (idx <= ((sizeP / sizeT) - 1)) );
        }

        template<typename V, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(V) < sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
        explicit Register(const V val, const u8 idx = 0) :
            value{ static_cast<T>((static_cast<T>(val) << sizeof(V)*CHAR_BIT*idx) &
                  std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max()) },
            previous_value{ 0 },
            bits{ value }
        {
            constexpr u16 sizeT = sizeof(T);
            constexpr u16 sizeP = sizeof(V);
            assert((idx >= 0) && (idx <= ((sizeT / sizeP) - 1)) );
        }

        template<typename V, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(V) == sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
        explicit Register(const V val, const u8 idx = 0) :
            value{ static_cast<T>( val ) }, previous_value{ 0 }, bits{ value }
        {}

        // the explicit on the copy constructor was the culprit
        template<typename V>
        /*explicit*/ Register(const Register<V>& reg, const u8 idx = 0) : Register(reg.value, idx) {}               

        Register& operator=(const Register& obj) {
            this->value = obj.value;
            this->previous_value = obj.previous_value;
            this->bits = obj.bits;
            return *this;
        }
    };      

} // namespace vpc
```

---

Here are some of the attempts at overloading - specializing the `operator=()`, these were inside of my class's declaration.

```
Reg8& operator=(const Reg16& rhs) {
    Reg8 temp{ rhs };
    this->value = temp.value;
    this->previous_value = temp.previous_value;
    this->bits = temp.bits;
    return *this;
}

Reg8& operator=(const Reg32& rhs) {
    Reg8 temp{ rhs };
    this->value = temp.value;
    this->previous_value = temp.previous_value;
    this->bits = temp.bits;
    return *this;
}

Reg8& operator=(const Reg64& rhs) {
    Reg8 temp{ rhs };
    this->value = temp.value;
    this->previous_value = temp.previous_value;
    this->bits = temp.bits;
    return *this;
}

Reg16& operator=(const Reg8& rhs) {
    Reg16 temp{ rhs };
    this->value = temp.value;
    this->previous_value = temp.previous_value;
    this->bits = temp.bits;
    return *this;
}


Reg16& operator=(const Reg32& rhs) {
    Reg16 temp{ rhs };
    this->value = temp.value;
    this->previous_value = temp.previous_value;
    this->bits = temp.bits;
    return *this;
}

Reg16& operator=(const Reg64& rhs) {
    Reg16 temp{ rhs };
    this->value = temp.value;
    this->previous_value = temp.previous_value;
    this->bits = temp.bits;
    return *this;
}
```

I believe there should be a way to be able to do this but I'm not sure how, and if I'm on the right path with specialization of these overloads, I don't know the proper syntax and Visual Studio is giving me this compiler error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestRegister, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\...\register.h(109): error C2556: 'vpc::Reg16 &vpc::Register<vpc::u8>::operator =(const vpc::Reg8 &)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'vpc::Register<vpc::u8> &vpc::Register<vpc::u8>::operator =(const vpc::Register<vpc::u8> &)'
1>c:\...\register.h(78): note: see declaration of 'vpc::Register<vpc::u8>::operator ='
1>c:\...\main.cpp(23): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'vpc::Register<vpc::u8>' being compiled
1>c:\...\register.h(109): error C2371: 'vpc::Register<vpc::u8>::operator =': redefinition; different basic types
1>c:\...\register.h(78): note: see declaration of 'vpc::Register<vpc::u8>::operator ='
1>c:\...\register.h(85): error C2556: 'vpc::Reg8 &vpc::Register<vpc::u16>::operator =(const vpc::Reg16 &)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'vpc::Register<vpc::u16> &vpc::Register<vpc::u16>::operator =(const vpc::Register<vpc::u16> &)'
1>c:\...\register.h(78): note: see declaration of 'vpc::Register<vpc::u16>::operator ='
1>c:\...\register.h(110): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'vpc::Register<vpc::u16>' being compiled
1>c:\...\register.h(85): error C2371: 'vpc::Register<vpc::u16>::operator =': redefinition; different basic types
1>c:\...\register.h(78): note: see declaration of 'vpc::Register<vpc::u16>::operator ='
1>c:\...\register.h(86): error C2079: 'vpc::Register<vpc::u16>::temp' uses undefined struct 'vpc::Register<vpc::u8>'
1>c:\...\register.h(87): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(87): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(88): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(88): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(89): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(89): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(90): error C2059: syntax error: 'return'
1>c:\...\register.h(90): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(93): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ''symbol''
1>c:\...\register.h(111): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(111): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(112): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(112): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(113): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(113): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(114): error C2059: syntax error: 'return'
1>c:\...\register.h(114): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(117): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ''symbol''
1>c:\...\main.cpp(29): error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'vpc::Reg8' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\...\register.h(78): note: could be 'vpc::Register<vpc::u16> &vpc::Register<vpc::u16>::operator =(const vpc::Register<vpc::u16> &)'
1>c:\...\main.cpp(29): note: while trying to match the argument list '(vpc::Reg16, vpc::Reg8)'
1>c:\...\register.h(101): error C2556: 'vpc::Reg8 &vpc::Register<vpc::u64>::operator =(const vpc::Reg64 &)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'vpc::Register<vpc::u64> &vpc::Register<vpc::u64>::operator =(const vpc::Register<vpc::u64> &)'
1>c:\...\register.h(78): note: see declaration of 'vpc::Register<vpc::u64>::operator ='
1>c:\...\main.cpp(141): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'vpc::Register<vpc::u64>' being compiled
1>c:\...\register.h(101): error C2371: 'vpc::Register<vpc::u64>::operator =': redefinition; different basic types
1>c:\...\register.h(78): note: see declaration of 'vpc::Register<vpc::u64>::operator ='
1>c:\...\register.h(103): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(103): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(104): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(104): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(105): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(105): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(106): error C2059: syntax error: 'return'
1>c:\...\register.h(106): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(109): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ''symbol''
1>c:\...\register.h(93): error C2556: 'vpc::Reg8 &vpc::Register<vpc::u32>::operator =(const vpc::Reg32 &)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'vpc::Register<vpc::u32> &vpc::Register<vpc::u32>::operator =(const vpc::Register<vpc::u32> &)'
1>c:\...\register.h(78): note: see declaration of 'vpc::Register<vpc::u32>::operator ='
1>c:\...\main.cpp(142): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'vpc::Register<vpc::u32>' being compiled
1>c:\...\register.h(93): error C2371: 'vpc::Register<vpc::u32>::operator =': redefinition; different basic types
1>c:\...\register.h(78): note: see declaration of 'vpc::Register<vpc::u32>::operator ='
1>c:\...\register.h(95): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(95): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(96): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(96): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(97): error C2059: syntax error: 'this'
1>c:\...\register.h(97): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(98): error C2059: syntax error: 'return'
1>c:\...\register.h(98): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\...\register.h(101): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ''symbol''
1>Done building project "TestRegister.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've tried many other ways, I've searched google, I've searched here looking for other Q/A's but couldn't seem to find anything relevant to my situation, unless if I overlooked something. What do I have to do to get this to compile?

**EDIT**

Both the copy constructor and assignment operator were failing because of the overlooked `explicit` on the `Copy Constructor`. This was giving me the plethora of visual studio compiler errors. Removing that explicit key word, resolved everything. And the `operator=()` that is in my class above is all that was needed. The overloads or specializations below the class section are not even need at all. Over 3 hours of trying to figure this out...

Comment: Please take a look at what a [mcve] is. There is so much here that is not in any way related to your question.

Comment: Simultaneous declaration and "assignment" is not assignment—`operator=` has no part in `Reg16 r16c = r8;` That's a constructor call, equivalent to `Reg16 r16c(static_cast<Reg16>(r8));`

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I shortened up my question as much a I could.

Comment: @HTNW Thank you for the heads, up on using the `static_cast` but I'm still after the `assignment operator=()`. I updated my question.

Comment: The description of "minimal" in the linked help states "Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem." The question here is hundreds of lines of code and contains many functions that are not necessary to demonstrate the problem. Many are not called at all. Many of the details of the ones that are aren't actually important for the purposes of the question. At the same time, now you removed the actual _question_ part of the question so it's not even clear what you're asking. As it stands, it's "here's a bunch of code, you figure out what I want."

Comment: I removed all of the class functions that were irrelevant to the question, and tried to make it as minimal as possible.

Comment: Please expand on your problem statement "Having trouble" and "keeps giving me the same compiler error". Your [mcve] should probably be a program of about 10 lines, with the error prominently displayed underneath it. 6 years and 130 questions and 470 answers in, you should know how this works by now!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've made a few small changes in my source, and I'm now getting a different compiler error. Originally when I posted this question, the compiler error wasn't from the operator=(), it was from the Assignment - copy constructor, which is now fixed by using static_cast. I'm updating my question as we speek.

Comment: This shows that you have not yet completed your debugging and are not yet at the "ask Stack Overflow" stage! Good luck.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can not debug if you can not compile!

Comment: @FrancisCugler Making attempts to fix a compilation error fits within the broad category "debugging", as I'm sure you know. Runtime debugging is but one particular kind of debugging! Good luck.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah but when you're staring at the same code for about 3 hours due to something of this nature... it gets frustrating. I thought my copy and assignment were okay, but never dawned on me about the `explicit` keyword reeking havoc... Sometimes you need a fresh set of eyes. I wanted to make sure they were working before I add my next set of constructors which are of the Variadic type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your code, an `operator=()` for different `Register<T>` types is simple

```
    template <typename U>
    Register & operator= (Register<U> const & obj)
     { return *this = Register{obj}; }
```

But when you write

```
    Reg16 r16c = r8;
```

you're calling a contructor, not `operator=()`.

It seems to me that you have to remove the `explicit` in

```
    template<typename V>
    explicit Register(const Register<V>& reg, const u8 idx = 0) : Register(reg.value, idx) {}
```

You have also to correct the main `operator=()` because `obj` is a reference, not a pointer; so you have to use point operator, not arrow operator

```
    Register& operator=(const Register& obj) {
        this->value = obj.value; // not obj->value
        this->previous_value = obj.previous_value; // not obj->previous_value
        this->bits = obj.bits; // not obj->bits
        return *this;
    };
```

En passant: your main `operator=()` isn't equal to thr default `operator=()`?

Comment: I updated my question, I still would like to keep it explicit. I had to use `static_cast<type>(obj)` to make the assignment constructor work. But the assignment operator I'm still having issues with.

Comment: @FrancisCugler - If you want to maintain it `explicit`, you have to write `Reg16 r16c = Reg16{r8};`. Anyway, there is also a problem in your main `operator=()`. Answer improved.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, and I fixed it within my source code.

Comment: @FrancisCugler - with that correction, and adding my template `operator=()`, `Reg16 r16d; r16d = r8;` compile in my platform.

Comment: `explicit` on a copy constructor is weird. Why would you like to keep it, Francis?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True, I've been at this most the day, I want the explicit on the constructors, but yeah on the copy it doesn't make sense... nice catch, that goes out to max66 too! I can correct that

Comment: Wow; all of this headache from the over looked `explicit` on the copy constructor. I didn't realize I had done that. Yeah I want the regular constructors and user defined constructors to be explicit but not the `copy constructor`. Due to this the assignment operator was failing and Visual Studio was giving hundreds of cryptic error compiler messages... I didn't even need to over load or specialize the `operator=()`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah by removing the explicit keyword on the copy constructor; everything works as it should. I can not believe I over looked that and the compiler errors were no help to point me in that direction either.